# How to select what posts goes into which page template in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a couple of custom pages in wordpress, how do i tell my page to get me only the posts i assign (if i could assign) to that page, is there a way to tell posts whose page they are for?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. This question appears to have nothing to do with programming. Can you please elaborate why it does?

Comment: its a php question, through php, you can achieve this and tie together a post and page.

Comment: Okay. Now I ask: What have you tried? Where are you so far so we can help you?

Comment: i have tried installing plugins, and working directly with tags and other categories within wordpress itself, but couldnt get it to work without a condition. and thats not really great, is there an optimal solution

Comment: It sounds like you are not working with PHP then [as defined by the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Generally, questions that don't pertain to code directly are off topic for Stack Overflow. Unless you have code you are working with that you can edit your question and put into it, I recommend asking your question on the [Wordpress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) instead, since you seem to be working with the WordPress  interface and not the API (that is, code).